# SQL - Displaying object names and types from user_objects data dictionary

Tags: sql, oracle, object

I am using Oracle. I am trying to view a table that looks like this

```
OBJECT_NAME         OBJECT_TYPE
-----------------   -----------
DEPARTMENT          TABLE
DEPARTMENT_ID_PK    INDEX
EMPLOYEE            TABLE
EMPLOYEE_ID_PK      INDEX
```

And this is what I have

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME, OBJECT_TYPE
FROM USER_OBJECTS
WHERE OBJECT_NAME IN ('EMPLOYEE', 'DEPARTMENT');
```

But the table that is printed only shows the Department and Employee object name and types, not the `department_id_pk` and `employee_id_pk`. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: MySQL <> Oracle. What are you using ?

Comment: Oracle. my apologies

Comment: Try `WHERE object_name LIKE 'EMPLOYEE%' OR object_name LIKE 'DEPARTMENT%'`

Comment: @KaushikNayak That worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This will work, if you are using naming standards and including the table name in the index and view names:

```
select
     object_name,
     object_type
from
     user_objects
where
     (object_name like '%EMPLOYEE%') 
OR   (object_name like '%DEPARTMENT%');
```

If no such standards are followed then you can use,

```
select 
    b.uniqueness, 
    a.index_name, 
    a.table_name, 
    a.column_name 
  from 
    user_ind_columns a, 
    user_indexes b 
where 
    a.index_name=b.index_name 
  and 
     ((object_name like '%EMPLOYEE%') or (object_name like '%DEPARTMENT%'))
order by 
    a.table_name, 
    a.index_name, 
    a.column_position;
```